# JavaScript login/signup callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, magento, jquery-events

I'm working on a Magento extension, all based on JavaScript and I need to integrate a widget from WordPress.
I have the event.js from view /widgets:

```
/* links events */
    var eventLinks = function() {
        var $loginBtn = my.html.find('.att-login'),
            $signupBtn = my.html.find('.att-signup');
        
        /* login btn event */
        $loginBtn.on('click', function() {
            BYND.widgets.log('[INFO]', '[LANDING PAGE] - Login button clicked');
            
            BYND.Auth.Login(function() {
                window.location.href = 'collections.html?page=my_collections';
            });
            
            return false;
        });
        
        /* signup btn event */
        $signupBtn.on('click', function() {
            BYND.widgets.log('[INFO]', '[LANDING PAGE] - Signup button clicked');
            
            BYND.Auth.Signup(function() {
                window.location.href = 'collections.html?page=my_collections';
            });
            
            return false;
        });
    },
```

And I need to make some callbacks for login/signup functions so my login box (already made in WP) pops up.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose function you are looking for (callback for signup) is here:

```
 BYND.Auth.Signup(function() {
            // replace that line with your code
            window.location.href = 'collections.html?page=my_collections';
        });
```

If you would like to show that page as a popup you could use another window, or iframe...